# How to carry forward data after successfull login into Facebook in Android

Tags: android

I have succesfully logged-in to facebook without any problem. After getting data from facebook I need to carry that data to another activity as soon as succesfully logged-in. Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    signUpWithFaceBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpUsingFaceBook);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    signUpWithFaceBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginButton.performClick();
        }
    });
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest
                    .GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("response", response.toString());
                    getData(object);
                }
            });
            //Graph API
            Bundle parameter = new Bundle();
            parameter.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name");
            request.setParameters(parameter);
            request.executeAsync();
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("firstName", firstname);
                intent.putExtra("lastName", lastname);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And in `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And,
This code is old one is still the same way to integrate FB in Android?

Comment: Call your startactivity method after `onCompleted` method of graph request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your data into `Bundle` and put it in `putExtras` to intent.
You get in `Bundle` in new `Activity`.

> While put data into `Bundle`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("firstName",firstname);
bundle.putString("lastName",lastname); 

Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class); 
i.putExtras(bundle); 
startActivity(i);
```

> Get `Bundle` at your `RegistrationActivity.java`

```
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   String fName = b.getString("firstName");
   String lName = b.getString("lastName");
```

> Also your `putExtras()` code in `getData()` after your `GraphRequest` Call

**Update**

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        System.out.println("onSuccess");
                        token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest
                                .GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.d("response", response.toString());
                                getData(object);

                                try {

                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("firstName",object.getString("first_name"));
                                    bundle.putString("lastName",object.getString("lastName"));


                                    Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        //Graph API
                        Bundle parameter = new Bundle();
                        parameter.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name");
                        request.setParameters(parameter);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }
    }
```

Comment: It carries null data. I did degub and seen data it is showing null  ` Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("firstName",firstname);
                    bundle.putString("lastName",lastname);
                    Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);`

Comment: Your answer is correct. I am getting data now, but initially when i installed app and log-in with facebook I am not geting any data. because `bundle.putString("firstName",firstname);` is running and it is null initially. Next it runs `firstname = object.getString("first_name");` in getData() where i am getting my data from FB. Any solution for this.

Comment: Now I am getting data in correct sequnce but unable to start another activity

Comment: Kabari I track the issue by debug. In your answer you changed last_name to lastName. that gives json exception lastName not found. any way thanks for the answer. my problem solved.

Comment: Oho Sorry its my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    String userID = (String) object.get("id");
                    String firstname = (String) object.get("first_name"); 
                    String lastname = (String) object.get("last_name");                                              

                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class); //MainActivity is current activity & NextActivity is any activity that is destination activity.
                     intent.putExtra("firstName", firstname);
                     intent.putExtra("lastName", lastname);
                     startActivity(intent);

                } catch (JSONException|Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: You started activity but you are going to any avtivity. I don't know what's happening here. I am a beginner

Comment: @sugiz sorry i cant get you. i put your intent code inside the onCompleted method of graphrequest. Bcoz graphrequest execute async so when you start activity at same time data value remains null.

Comment: There is problem how to start another activity you can check here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java & simply change your intent to `Intent i = new Intent(Mainactivity.this,NextActivity.class)`...